# Stop pulling data from an API after a specific amount of time

Tags: python, python-requests

I am pulling some data from a streaming API using python v3, I need to stop pulling that data after 60 seconds. Also if anyone has suggestions on chunk_size or some alternative for streaming I'd be open to that. 
So far this is what I have:

```
response = requests.get('link to site', stream=True)

for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=100):
    print(data)
```

Comment: How strict is the timeout? Is it okay to let the current get finish or does it need to return right away?

Comment: 60 seconds minimum so if it goes a little longer that's fine.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? This seems like the kind of topic on which there should be plenty of information available, no?

Answer (score 1):

More speculation than answer, but you could set a timer and then close the response. This may do it but I don't have a good way to test it. I don't know which exception to expect when the response is closed so I catch them all and print so the code can be changed.

```
import threading

response = requests.get('link to site', stream=True)
timer = threading.Timer(60, response.close)
try:
    timer.start()
    for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=100):
        print(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("you want to catch this", e)
finally:
    timer.cancel()
```